# View.resetResolvedLayoutDirection crashes my app when using addView()

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I'm relatively new to android, I was tasked with creating a custom view that imitates the behavior of a card view, but can be collapsed and expanded, I don't know what the collapsible section of the component will have, since the idea is to make a generic component that can be reused anywhere, thus, I'm trying to add the view's children to the collapsible section in the XML of the component, however, whenever I try to run this method

```
fun addChildrenToCollapsableSection() {
   for(childIndex in 0 until childCount) {
        val child = this.getChildAt(childIndex)val parent = child.parent as ViewGroup
        if(parent.isNotEmpty() || parent == this) {
            parent.removeView(child)
            collapsableSection.addView(child)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the next stacktrace

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB
        at android.view.View.getRawLayoutDirection(View.java:11966)
        at android.view.View.isLayoutDirectionInherited(View.java:20192)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7814)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
2022-11-09 11:50:07.003 25605-25605/com.mdlive.mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
2022-11-09 11:50:07.345 25605-25605/com.mdlive.mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
2022-11-09 11:50:07.345 25605-25605/com.mdlive.mobile E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:7815)
        at android.view.View.resetRtlProperties(View.java:19999)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5286)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5004)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4976)
```

Here is my component's XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topSection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleCollapsableCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Patient"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Patient" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stateIndicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/titleCollapsableCard"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Completed" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapsableIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/generic_expandable_button_collapsed"
            android:src="@drawable/fwf__card_view_collapse"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsableSection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/topSection" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is where I'm using it

```
<com.package.packagecore.packagecustomviews.ReviewCollapsableCard
                android:id="@+id/stub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                app:isCollapsable="true"
                app:setCollapsed="false">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TESTING COLLAPSABILITY"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

 </com.package.packagecore.packagecustomviews.ReviewCollapsableCard>
```

I tried nullifying layout transitions and adding layout parameters, it didn't work